# When does a common divisor of a and b generate the same ideal of a and b?

Tags: ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm, principal-ideal-domains

Let R be a unitary commutative ring: let $a,b,d\in R$. I'm trying to prove that

$\langle d \rangle = \langle a,b \rangle \Leftrightarrow d = \gcd(a,b)$

I can prove the $\Rightarrow$ part. The $\Leftarrow$ part is easy to prove in a ring in which every ideal is principal, but does it holds in a generic unitary commutative ring?

[Edit]
For $\gcd(a,b)$ i mean that let be $d$ an element of $R$ so $d\in \gcd(a,b)$ iff $d|a$ and $d|b$ and $\forall d' \in R: d'|a \land d'|b \Rightarrow d'|d$ . The equal sign I used before is a light abuse of notation since uniqueness is not granted using this definition.

Comment: No. In $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ we have $\gcd(x,y)=1$ but $(1)\not=(x,y)$.

Comment: Concerning the forward implication, in the integers, $\langle-1\rangle=\langle2,3\rangle$ but $-1\ne\gcd(2,3)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This depends on the definition of gcd. I was using the following definition, that is common in ring theory (or at least it is the definition that we use in our course): let R be a commutative ring:

$d \in \gcd(a,b)$ iff $d|a$ and  $d|b$ and $\forall d'\in R: d'|a \land d'|b \Rightarrow d'|d$

Note that the equal sign of my original post was a light abuse of notation, since uniqueness of gcd is not garanted. Using this definition in $\mathbb{Z}$ we can prove that $-1$ indeed is a $\gcd(2,3)$.
I will add some clarifications to original post.